# Session and Request object dilemma

Tags: php, symfony, architecture

Session is retrieved in SF2 through the Request object. Hmm, this becomes kind of problematical when some architecture is considered - in cases where access to a session vars is needed from within a service.

Or perhaps, I'm not quite correct in this matter? (Hope so).

Obviously each request from a user through a webbrowser *is* a Request. So as long as we use controller actions in standard SF2, we have Request. But should we then pass the Request object to any service we need?

Passing Request object to all of the services that needs their methods to be run (e.g. storing info, checking settings, putting filters for displaying data etc. - well in some bigger apps it's quite a lot of them!) because it *might* be needed because of the dependent services, seems to be a very stupid idea to me. It also breaks the "S" in [S.O.L.I.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) recommendation for OOP.

So I came up to a conclusion I need either to:

1. Pass the Request obj to many services just because the dependant service *might* need *some* data from it (i.e. broken "S" as above)
2. Retrieve and process data from Request every time I needed in every single controller action (i.e. code duplication) - in this case I don't pass a Request obj, but previously prepare all data needed - but I must do it then in many action methods in almost all controllers (retrieving/processing data from Request is just a simple call for another service, but then it's not centralized)

I'm putting this question, because I have e.g. the following problem to solve:

1. I'm using the same filters for all different data (from different data-sources) on the whole page.
2. Filters can be enabled and disabled - and they should be remembered for all the pages for the single session
3. I decided that saving "disabled" filters to a session is probably the best approach (because by default all data should be seen, i.e. all filters should be in "enable" state)

The 3rd point - saving data (filters) to a session - is what makes trouble in SF2, as described above. For displaying filtered data on page, I need access to a session, and thus access to the Request obj. And this means I have difficulties in keeping "S" in SOLID, because of making dependency on a service's method to always pass a Request obj to it.

Is there any other, better solution than the 2 mentioned (i.e. one, breaking SOLID, or two, code duplication)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session is also a service in the symfony di container, you can simply inject session into your servives